Angular MEAN stack model/controller not saving to MongoDB Atlas
I'm following a tutorial, and I'm stuck on this problem, The model is not passing data to the MongoDB Atlas Database. I'm trying to post data with Postman, but I get a status 200 ok, but it does not give me a status 201 "user created successfully." I suspect that the Mongoose schema in the model is not correct. I read the Mongoose docs, but I keep having the same problem.
here are the code snippets:
UserModel.js
    

    const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true, min: 4, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    });
    const User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
    export default User;

fault in UserModel.js;
the tutorial says use username:{types:String, etc...},

but I get an error TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: true is not a valid type at path required, and in the  mongoose docs it describes that you should use username:{type: String, etc...},

AuthController.js
    export const signup = async (req, res) => {
     const { username, password } = req.body;
     const hashedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(password, 10);
     const newUser = new User({ username, password: hashedPassword });
     try {
     const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });
     if (existingUser) {
      throw errorHandler(409, "User already exists in database!");
      }
     await newUser.save();
     res.status(201).json("User has been created successfully!");
     } catch (error) {
     console.error(error.message);
     res.status(error.statusCode).json(error.message);
     }
    };

Index.js
    const app = express();
     app.use(express.json());
     dotenv.config();
     app.use(cookieParser());
     app.listen(process.env.Server, () =>
     console.log("Server is runnning on port 4000!")
    );

    app.use("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
    res.json("Hello from Mongo server!");
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json("Error:500 Internal server error!");
    }
   });
   mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MongoDB)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("successfully Conected to MongoDB!");
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function () {
    if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
    if (process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGINS) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("server not allowed by CORS!"));
    }
  },
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, path.join(__dirname, "public"));
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

export const upload = multer({ storage });
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.upload = upload;
  next();
});

app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/api/post", postRouter);
app.use("/api/post/upload", upload.single("file"), postRouterUpload);
app.use("/upload", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

I revised the tutorial twice to see if i didn't make any typo's and read the mongoose documentation on using the proper schema types
